# How to use ohai gem

Tags: ruby, ohai-gem

In the OpsCode Wiki there is there following documentation:

```
require 'ohai'

# ...
# Profit! ;-)
```

How can I print the JSON data provided by the 'ohai' command but using IRB? I tried to see the code in application.rb but I get empty data.

```
require 'ohai/application'
ohai = Ohai::System.new
ohai.json_pretty_print
 => "{\n\n}"
```

I am **not** trying to do this within Chef (or [Shef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Shef)), I just want to use the ohai gem itself, in my own app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poking about in the `Ohai::Application` class (what you get when you run `ohai`), [`#run_application`](https://github.com/opscode/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/application.rb#L92) instantiates `Ohai::System` and, unless it was configured by a file, it calls `all_plugins` to populate it with data.

Presumably, `Ohai::System#all_plugins` delegates the data collection to [the `lib/ohai/plugins` directory](https://github.com/opscode/ohai/tree/master/lib/ohai/plugins).

```
$ irb -rohai
> system = Ohai::System.new
 => #<Ohai::System:0x00000100988950 @data={}, @seen_plugins={}, @providers={}, @plugin_path="", @hints={}> 
> system.all_plugins
 => true 
> puts system.to_json
{"languages":{"ruby":{"platform":"x86_64-darwin10.8.0","version":"1.9.2", ...
> system.to_json.size
 => 42395
```

Answer (score 2):

I too searched for a simple and good library to do that...

I came across

> Usagewatch

and after 5 minutes had my monitoring.rb done..

Install : gem install usagewatch

Install on mac : gem install usagewatch_ext

Refer to [this](http://www.philchen.com/2013/07/17/linux-usage-statistics-using-ruby-gem-usagewatch) article for more info